# How to scale only a half of a view (android animation)

Tags: android

Is there anyway to apply scale animation on only a half of the view?
I want to apply animation on the left part of the view, and the right part remains normal size.

Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ImageView You could split the image in two and animate only the half you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks! It's not a ImageView but a custom view.